# Is this true: "In MySQL, fetching a column value forces a read of the entire row"?

Tags: mysql, database-performance, query-performance

I just read this statement in a conference speaker slide, from somebody who seems to know what he is talking about:

> In MySQL, fetching a column value forces a read of the entire row [so aggressivly fetching contents there makes sense].

So my question is: Does this mean that in a multi-column database table query the following queries cost exactly the same ? I'm asking because this crosses quite everything i've ever heard about MySQL before.

**Query 1:**

```
SELECT id FROM mytable WHERE flag = 1;
```

**Query 2:**

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE flag = 1;
```

Comment: It depends on the indexes you have and data distribution.

Answer (score 4):

I guess this is not correct. I remember clearly my graduation teacher telling us cases where the performance of a certain application was really bad because of the use of 'SELECT *...' instead of using 'SELECT id...', for example.

Maybe you can try to make a real example running a timestamp before and after a sequence of SQL queries in both ways and comparing its results.

**EDIT**: Trying a simple Schema on SQL Fiddle (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/32954/2) with `SELECT * FROM table` and `SELECT id FROM table`, the average time for the '*' one was about 10 ms for 95 rows and the average time for the 'id' one was 1 ms for the same 95 rows. I don't know if SQL Fiddle is a trustable source, but I think it can give us an idea.

Answer (score 1):

This is correct information on `MS SQL` when we would talk about disc operations.
One simple select including one simple identifier reads more than one row.

IMHO MSSQL DB `Fetch` operation reads 8 pages (512kb?) of data into a DB cache. That's the reason why clustered index including data or reading of data using consequent natural increasing identifier is so mighty. Database read couple of rows into cache within first disc fetch and if following select hits the catch it does not have to go to hard disc.

Note that there is definitely difference between

```
SELECT * FROM ...
```

and

```
SELECT ID FROM ...
```

The server does not have to serialize all properties, network transport takes a time too and client deserialization as well.